# How to find IP address of Facebook Chat user using wireshark?

Tags: facebook, cmd, ip, wireshark

I want to find out a person's ip address who is abusing me on facebook. Whenever I log into facebook he shows up in the chat and threatens me. I am kinda hacker but how can I find his ip address in chat using wireshark or something. He is really starting to piss me off. Please HELP.

Comment: No there is no way to find his ip address because he connects to Facebooks servers and not your computer. Report him to Facebook

Comment: are you sure? Please just tell me or is it against you principles or the website's policy?

Comment: You can only monitor traffic if it is sent or received by you.

Comment: Yes, he's sure. You would find just facebook's address, but don't hack it accidentally please

Comment: I want to make him pay. Is there any software or something?

Comment: what are you trying to say pajaja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wireshark is a fantastic tool but will only be able to monitor network traffic passing through your own network - in this instance, you would be able to monitor your own side of the Facebook Messenger conversation.

There is no direct TCP/IP connection from this person's computer to your computer involved. Both they and you connect to Facebook's web servers and messages are sent and received using HTTP protocol and AJAX.

Most communication services operate in this way these days, partly to protect the privacy of its users, partly for improved performance and reliability, and partly for regulatory compliance. Possible solutions normally include:

- Reporting abuse to the service provider and in most cases they will be pleased to investigate it for you;
- Blocking the person from contacting you in future using the tools built-in to the service;
- Reporting abuse to your local Police, who can legally obtain the IP address and login history from Facebook. They will not pass this information onto you for retribution but if sufficient evidence is available the person bothering you could be arrested and charged for harassment, malicious communications, defamation and/or breach of peace, depending on the local laws where you/they live.

  Reference: [CyberSmile.org: CyberBullying and the Law](http://www.cybersmile.org/advice-help/category/cyberbullying-and-the-law)